# Bootstrap modal not show

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am using php.My link generate from controller.

$retailer["url"] like as 0125myimage.jpg

```
<a onClick="crop('.$retailer["url"].')" data-target="#styledModal3" href="#" class="fa fa-edit lupa"></a>
```

My javascript function

```
function crop(imgurl)
{
    $('#preview').attr('src',imgurl);

    $('div#styledModal3').load(function(){

        $(this).modal({

            keyboard:true,
            backdrop:true
        });
    }).modal('show');

}
```

when I click in my link then modal not show.

Answer (score 0):

.modal('show') calling before modal initialization $(this).modal({

function you used as argument in $('div#styledModal3').load( is just a success callback which fired only after load has completed. So initialization is called after you trying to show your modal.

Your code should looks like this

```
function crop(imgurl)
{
    $('#preview').attr('src',imgurl);

    $('div#styledModal3').load(function(){

        $(this).modal({

            keyboard:true,
            backdrop:true,
            show: true
        });
    });

}
```

Comment: Or just do `$(this).modal({ keyboard:true, backdrop:true });` It works without the `show` option.